# How do you create a category (or select an existing one) from a field value on a Page Form in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I created a form to allow users to input data about scientific topics, references and categories in an organized manner. Problem is, I am unable to automatically categorize the page (by either creating a new category or using an existing one) when a user fills the form with the appropriate category information.

Here is the template page from my Mediawiki site:

```
<noinclude>
{{#template_params:Summary (label=Topic Summary (In point form, as a numbered list. Include references between <ref></ref> tags.))|User_Category}}
</noinclude><includeonly>
{{#template_display:_format=sections}}
[[Category:Summary Article]]
[[Category:{{#arraymap:|,|@@||}}]]
</includeonly>
```

Here's my form code:

```
<noinclude>
This is the "Summary Article" form.
To create a page with this form, enter the page name below;
if a page with that name already exists, you will be sent to a form to edit that page.

{{#forminput:form=Summary Article}}

</noinclude><includeonly>
<div id="wikiPreview" style="display: none; padding-bottom: 25px; margin-bottom: 25px; border-bottom: 1px solid #AAAAAA;"></div>
=Summary=
{{{section|Summary|level=1}}}

==Category==
{{{field|User_Category|level=2}}}

</includeonly>
```

I attempted to assign the field value to the category variable `User_Category` in order to create a category in the page, but was unsuccessful. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the solution, which is similar to the one above - but does not cause errors. Here's the template:

```
<noinclude>
{{#template_params:Summary|Categories}}
{{#template_display:_format=sections}}
</noinclude><includeonly>
[[Category:Summary Article]]
{{#arraymap:{{{Categories|}}}|,|x|[[Category:x]]|\s}}
</includeonly>
```

Here's the form:

```
<noinclude>
This is the "Summary Article" form.
To create a page with this form, enter the page name below;
if a page with that name already exists, you will be sent to a form to edit that page.

{{#forminput:form=Summary Article}}

</noinclude><includeonly>
<div id="wikiPreview" style="display: none; padding-bottom: 25px; margin-bottom: 25px; border-bottom: 1px solid #AAAAAA;"></div>
{{{for template|Summary Article}}}
==Summary==
{{{section|Summary|mandatory|rows=20}}}

==Category==
{{{field|Categories|input type=tokens|values from namespace=Category}}}

</includeonly>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should specify the input type of your field, in your case, `tokens` should be appropriate.

Then tell the field to take values from the category list, you can achieve this with `values from namespace` attribute.

```
{{{field|User_Category|input type=tokens|values from namespace=Category}}}
```

Second, your template has no reference to the field name `User_Category`. This should be the `arraymap` data :

> {{#arraymap:{{{User_Category}}}||@@| [[Category:@@]] }}

Comment: Thank you for your help, I used your idea to hit upon a solution. There’s another question I put up on Stack Overflow about MediaWiki Page Forms, if you’re interested.